# Delete specific words from line in mysql log

Tags: mysql, regex, linux

I have a log file like this

```
15-31-57.175 [4359] [TRACE] ThreadUpdateDb::insertUpdate() id[1791145] sqlquery[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:57','Electrolux', 'abandoned', '1609507904.86839', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01008367900', '886123', 'CALL')]
15-31-59.104 [4361] [TRACE] ThreadUpdateDb::insertUpdate() id[1791170] sqlquery[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'queued', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')]
```

I need a linux command to delete all words before 'sqlquery' to be like this

```
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:57','Electrolux', 'abandoned', '1609507904.86839', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01008367900', '886123', 'CALL')]
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'queued', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{.*sqlquery}{}' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

Or use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'sqlquery\K.*' in_file > out_file
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)